# SQLalchemy retrieving id of row by filters

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to get the id of a row by using 2 filters.
I get it to work by using 1 filter, but as soon as I add the second, things go wrong. Can someone please help (yes I have read the sqlalchemy tutorial, but still with the problem)

My table (part of it)

```
class Character(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'character'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    lock = Column(Boolean)
```

I created an empty row in the table with only the user_id filled in.

Now this line work (the 1 filter)

```
u_id = 1
x_char = session.query(Character).filter_by(user_id=u_id).first()
y = x_char.id
print y
```

When I try to add the second filter (which still stands on null) it goes wrong.
I get the following error: AttributeError:'Query' object has no atribute 'id'

```
x_char = session.query(Character).filter(and_(Character.user_id == u_id, Character.lock == None))
y = x_char.id
print y
```

Please help me out or point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to call `.first()`, so your query was not executed *at all*:

```
x_char = session.query(Character).filter(and_(Character.user_id == u_id, Character.lock == None))
x_char = x_char.first()
```

If this query doesn't return anything, `x_char` will be `None`. To debug *why* the query doesn't return anything, you could print the generated SQL to help you understand what SQLAlchemy is sending to the database:

```
x_char = session.query(Character).filter(and_(Character.user_id == u_id, Character.lock == None))
print x_char
```

Comment: @HansdeJong: I very much doubt that. `.first()` does *not* return a `Query` object, so the error will *at the very least* be different for what type of object this returns.

Comment: @HansdeJong: What is the error message that you see, if it is the exact same `AttributeError` for `id` on `Query` objects, you didn't apply the `.first()` call properly. If it is different, please do share that error.

Comment: Excuse me, the error changed indeed. AttributeError" 'NonType' object has no attribute 'id'

If i check with SQLite Studio, the row is there with an id of 1

Comment: @HansdeJong: If the return value of `.first()` is None, then the database doesn't agree with you. Use `print x_char` instead of calling `xchar.first()` to see the SQL query being executed.

Comment: Finally, I got it. Thanks for the help. 
Kind of sure i tried the .first() before as well. I changed lock to lokk thought maybe lock would be recognised as something else.